# can we convert cakephp application from version 1.3 to 3.1

Tags: cakephp

I have one application developed in cakephp 1.3 version. It is working fine. Now I want to add some new modules in that application. Please suggest do I need to migrate my application to cakephp latest version and then start developing new modules, or leave the application in old version and aa new modules. Will there be any advantage of upgrading the version of cakephp?

Comment: Yes you can, but you need time. Backup your db, create  new cakephp project, backe code, improve layout and app code. Easy migration ?

Comment: There are many advantages to upgrading, but it's a lot of work. Whether it's worthwhile for your project is a question only you can answer. If you're going to upgrade, though, you should go to 3.7 instead of 3.1.

Comment: Thanks Salines and Greg for your response. Can you please give me the URL which will help me to migrate from version 1.3 to 3.7